# How IAM users sign into AWS accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I followed the AWS documentation [How IAM Users Sign In to Your AWS Account](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users_sign-in.html) to sign in IAM with the link,

```
https://username.aws.amazon.com/console
```

I don't know what's the `Account`? I tried to fill my root account (an email), but failed to log in.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to IAM dashboard. You will see the sign in link there. Use that URL to sign in. When you use that URL, `Account` will be pre filled.

`https://AWS-account-ID-or-alias.signin.aws.amazon.com/console` - It is the account ID not the user ID.

[image]